# How to store constants (e.g., text string) for use in different View files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, constants

I have a block of disclaimer text used across multiple pages/ partials. I figure I could:

1. make this block of text a partial itself and then call this partial whenever I need
2. save this block of text as an environment variable
3. save this block of text as a shared method with an instance variable, and then include that instance variable in all the methods corresponding with pages that need it like so:

Example of #3:

```
def disclaimer
    @text = "text"
end

def homepage
    disclaimer
end

def page_one
    disclaimer
end

# then the view file for homepage or page_one would just call  @text
```

Which of these ways is more "Rails"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your question, there are a few ways to do this. Your best best is to either use a partial, or make a helper and define a method for your disclaimer in the helper.

Helpers should be a bit faster, because they aren't rendering the partial. This is the best bet if your disclaimer is static text. If you are using any HTML in your disclaimer, it would probably be better to use a partial.

Example helper:

```
module DisclaimerHelper
  def disclaimer
    "This is the static text of my disclaimer."
  end
end
```

Comment: The helper method is pretty similar to method #3, except you don't access it in your controller. Helpers are available directly from the view, as long as you place them in app/helpers.

Comment: I've added an example of a helper definition. To use it, you would just use `<%= disclaimer %>` in your .html.erb, or `= disclaimer` if you are using HAML.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with option 1. Environment variables are usually reserved for credentials to services that your app uses and option 3 seems like it would be a little more complex than option 1.